# $_POST in dynamic form only store last value from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem, when I retrieve the value from the $_POST variable, the value taken is the last value printed.

```
<?php
      foreach($mlbb as $s){
      ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->

          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner"> 
              <h3><?php echo $s->layanan."<br>".$s->harga." Poin" ?></h3>
            </div>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'mlbb/beli_aksi'; ?> " method="post" id="form-satuan" >
            <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $s->id;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="harga" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $s->harga;?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Beli">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->

      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: please try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208793/store-dynamically-created-elements-value-to-database-php-mysql

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: you can use the input name value as an array name="id[]".

Comment: It's because you need to envelop all inputs inside one `<form></form>` element. When you submit a form, only the `<input> </input>` elements inside that form gets posted. Names need to be unique or you can use `<input name="input_array[maybesomekey]"/>` syntax to envelop all under one array in $_POST global